# Thunderbolt Display on non Apple computer

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, thunderbolt

I just got a System76 Galago UltraPro, and I'm trying to hook it up with my [Thunderbolt Display A1407](http://www.everymac.com/monitors/apple/thunderbolt/specs/apple-thunderbolt-display-27-inch-specs.html).

I have tried by using both the Mini DisplayPort from the display to the computer, and a converter from HDMI to Mini DP, but none of those work.

As recommended by many posts on the web, I've also installed the additional drivers.

The graphics card is Intel® Iris Pro 5200 – 128 MB eDRAM.

Any ideas?

Comment: As you bought from System76 which designs their hardware to run with ubuntu, have you asked them for an answer?

Comment: I have. No answer yet. Will update if they respond.

Comment: What did you end up doing? I am thinking of buying a system76 galago and I was wondering if it works with the thunderbolt displays.

Answer (score 0):

The only way it works for me is to use a Thunderbolt Docking Station like belkin thunderbolt 2 dock or kanex thunderbolt dock. with this both the apple thunderbolt display works as a Display but the ports (ethernet, firewire,usb) are not usable. so its not a cheap solution.